# Vue, click on table cell with data and show that data in modal

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a modal in my vue component, which is working well if I just put static text in it, so I know it's perfectly functional

However, trying to pass data from the table cell being clicked into the modal is failing and saying that `name` is undefined.

What am I doing wrong trying to pass data for each cell into this modal?

```
<div id="app">
  <table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td v-for="name in names"  @click="showDetailModal = true"></td>
      <td>@{{ name }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>


  <div class="modal-vue">
    <!-- overlay to help with readability of modal -->
    <div class="overlay" v-if="showDetailModal" @click="showDetailModal = false"></div>

    <!-- Modal for detail on table cell click event -->
    <div class="modal" v-if="showDetailModal">
      <button class="close" @click="showDetailModal = false">x</button>
      <h3>@{{ name.age }}</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  props: { 

  },
  data: {
    showDetailModal: false,
    names: [
      {
        "name":"Amy",
        "age":37
      },
      {
        "name":"James",
        "age":39
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create another data property called `currentItem` then assign the click item to it when you click on the table row :

```
<div id="app">
  <table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td v-for="name in names"  @click="showModal(name )"></td>
      <td>@{{ name }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>


  <div class="modal-vue">
    <!-- overlay to help with readability of modal -->
    <div class="overlay" v-if="showDetailModal" @click="showDetailModal = false"></div>

    <!-- Modal for detail on table cell click event -->
    <div class="modal" v-if="showDetailModal">
      <button class="close" @click="showDetailModal = false">x</button>
      <h3>@{{ currentItem.age }}</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  props: { 

  },
  data: {
    showDetailModal: false,
    names: [
      {
        "name":"Amy",
        "age":37
      },
      {
        "name":"James",
        "age":39
      }
    ],
    currentItem:{name:'',age:''}
  },
methods:{
  showModal(item){
     this.showDetailModal = true;
     this.currentItem=item
  }

}
})
```

Comment: So the function is being called properly because I can print a console.log within the function, however, the modal now no longer shows up. I even printed the status of showDetailModal to the console and it shows the correct status but the modal isn't showing now

Comment: you're welcome, I've made mistake, it should be `this.showDetailModal = true;` instead of `showDetailModal = true,`

Answer (score 0):

The reason for `name` resulting undefined is because it lives only inside the `v-for` loop.

For this reason, when the table gets clicked, you need to store which user has been clicked. This way, the modal can show the selected user based on that value.

The solution suggested from Boussadjra Brahim works great, however maybe it could be a little cleaner by removing `showDetailModal` data.

```
<div id="app">
  <table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td v-for="name in names"  @click="showModal(name )"></td>
      <td>@{{ name }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>


  <div class="modal-vue">
    <!-- overlay to help with readability of modal -->
    <div class="overlay" v-if="currentItem" @click="currentItem = false"></div>

    <!-- Modal for detail on table cell click event -->
    <div class="modal" v-if="currentItem">
      <button class="close" @click="currentItem = false">x</button>
      <h3>@{{ currentItem.age }}</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  props: { 

  },
  data: {
    names: [
      {
        "name":"Amy",
        "age":37
      },
      {
        "name":"James",
        "age":39
      }
    ],
    currentItem: false
  },
methods:{
  showModal(item){
     this.currentItem=item
  }

}
})
```